# How to retrieve Quiz questions on iOS app and print result?

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures

I'm trying to build a Quiz Application with swift for iOS. I have to put 450 Questions, but this will take a lot of lines on the swift file. You can see my 4 questions got 4 lines on the code, think about 450 questions. Is there any suggestion on what to do so that I can retrieve the Questions from another file? Is there going to happen any ram overload and make the app crash? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

struct Question {
    var Question: String!
    var Answers: [String]!
    var Answer: Int!
}

class LittleTestViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

    var Questions = [Question]()
    var QNumber = Int()
    var answerNumber = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Questions = [
            Question(Question:"KEK1.Tα Συστήματα μη Επανδρωμένων Αεροσκαφών(ΣμηΕΑ) επιτρέπεται να ίπτανται:", Answers: ["α) Με μέγιστο ύψος τα 400 πόδια (FT) επάνω από το έδαφος ή την επιφάνεια της θάλασσας (AGL,MSL).","β)Εντός Προσωρινών Αποκλειστικών Περιοχών (Temporary Segregated Areas TSA) για πτήσεις ΣμηΕΑ.","γ)Σε καθορισμένα ίχνη και ύψη που προσδιορίζονται με ειδικές άδειες των Υπηρεσιών Εναέριας Κυκλοφορίας της ΥΠΑ.","δ) Όλες οι απαντήσεις είναι σωστές."], Answer: 3),
            Question(Question:"ΚΕK2. Παρέχεται υπηρεσία Ελέγχου Εναέριας Κυκλοφορίας ‐ ΕΕΚ (Air Traffic Control‐ATC) στις πτήσεις ΣμηΕΑ;", Answers: ["α) Όχι, δεν παρέχονται υπηρεσίες εναέριας κυκλοφορίας ‐ ΕΚ (Air Traffic Services ‐ATS)","β) Ναι, παρέχεται υπηρεσία Ελέγχου Εναέριας Κυκλοφορίας (ATC).","γ) Όταν απαιτείται, οι Υπηρεσίες Εναέριας Κυκλοφορίας της ΥΠΑ εκδίδουν ειδικές άδειες και οδηγίες.","δ) Οι απαντήσεις α και γ είναι σωστές."], Answer: 3),
        Question(Question:"KEK3. Τα ΣμηΕΑ (UAS) επιτρέπεται να πετούν:", Answers: ["α) Κάτω από ύψος 400 ποδιών, δηλαδή, κάτω από τα επιτρεπόμενα όρια για την κυκλοφορία επανδρωμένων αεροσκαφών.","β) Εντός προσωρινών περιοχών που προσδιορίζονται από τις υπηρεσίες εναέριας κυκλοφορίας της ΥΠΑ.","γ) Κάτω από ύψος 46.000 ποδιών, δηλαδή, κάνω από τα ανώτερα όρια του εναέριου χώρου για την κυκλοφορία επανδρωμένων αεροσκαφών.","δ) Οι απαντήσεις α και β είναι σωστές."], Answer: 3),
        Question(Question:"ΚΕK4. Η διεξαγωγή Πτήσεων ΣμηΕΑ (UAS) απαγορεύεται γενικά σε εναέριο χώρο:", Answers: ["α) Σε περιοχές που διενεργούνται πτήσεις επανδρωμένων αεροσκαφών.","β) Σε απόσταση μικρότερη των 8 χιλιομέτρων από αεροδρόμια.","γ) Απαγορεύεται η πτήση ΣμηΕΑ (UAS) ανοικτής (Open) κατηγορίας επάνω από συγκεντρώσεις προσώπων.","δ) Όλες οι απαντήσεις είναι σωστές."], Answer: 3)]


        pickQuestion()

    }

    func pickQuestion ()
    {
        if Questions.count > 0 {
            QNumber = Questions.count
            questionLabel.text = Questions[QNumber].Question

            answerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer

            for i in 0..<buttons.count{
                buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
            Questions.remove(at: QNumber)
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("Done")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func bt1(_ sender: Any) {
        if answerNumber == 0 {
            pickQuestion()
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("Wrong!")
            pickQuestion()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func btn2(_ sender: Any) {
        if answerNumber == 1 {
            pickQuestion()
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("Wrong!")
            pickQuestion()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func btn3(_ sender: Any) {
        if answerNumber == 2 {
            pickQuestion()
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("Wrong!")
            pickQuestion()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func btn4(_ sender: Any) {
        if answerNumber == 3 {
            pickQuestion()
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog("Wrong!")
            pickQuestion()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `JSON` file containing all your data, i.e

**1.** **Questions.json**

```
 [{"question":"ques1","answers":["ans1", "ans2", "ans3"], "answer": 1},
 {"question":"ques2","answers":["ans1", "ans2", "ans3"], "answer": 2},
 {"question":"ques3","answers":["ans1", "ans2", "ans3"], "answer": 3}]
```

**2.** **Read the contents of file and create your `questions array`**

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Questions", ofType: "json")
    {
        if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe), options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)) as? [[String : Any]]
        {
            var questionsArray = [Question]()
            for item in array
            {
                questionsArray.append(Question(item: item))
            }
            print(questionsArray)
        }
    }
```

**3.** **`Question struct`**:

```
struct Question
{
    var Question: String?
    var Answers: [String]?
    var Answer: Int?

    init(item: [String: Any])
    {
        self.Question = item["question"] as? String
        self.Answers = item["answers"] as? [String]
        self.Answer = item["answer"] as? Int
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your json file?

Comment: Check if the file is included in the target.

Comment: Also, check if the json that you have added to your json file is in correct format.

Comment: Check in the finder what is the extension of your json file.

Comment: I think you have created a plain text document. Just try downloading a sample file from http://sample-file.bazadanni.com/2012/01/json.html . Change the name and content of the file and drop it into your project. Then check if it works.

Comment: In the for loop use self.Questions instead of questionsArray.

Comment: questionsArray is just a temporary variable that I have created. Remove it and use self.Questions. I think it is very straightforward to figure out now.

Comment: Just add the code that you are using. I’ll look into it.

Comment: Also mark the line at which you are getting this exception.

Comment: You are trying to access an index on Questions array that doesn’t exist. Check the value of QNumber. It must be less than the number of elements in your array. That was just a sample json I have shown you. Don’t forget adding your own data to it.

Comment: Sure..Happy coding..:)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try out `.plist` since the questions and answers are *static* content. You can make use of `UserDefaults` to track the right vs. wrong count.

However, if you are considering to expand your question set,you should have a look at SQLite / CoreData.